# Cookie is not set on cross domain

Tags: angularjs, cookies, proxy, cross-domain, node-http-proxy

I am making an angularjs cordova apps. To login we must perform to another domain a first request to `/login` and the the response has an entry called `cookie` which contains the cookie we must set in order to login.

The problem is that when I'm developping with `ionic serve` (so in my browser), there is that awful thing called CORS. And since the other site which I want to connect to doesn't allow CORS I was forced to use a proxy using `node-http-proxy`, which proxied the requests and added CORS headers. Then, when I needed to connect to the other website, I made requests on my proxy.  But now I need to login as explained before.

So I put this code to my proxy which parses the response of the `/login` route and extracted the cookie simply:

```
connect.createServer(
  function(req, res, next) {
    res.oldWrite = res.write;
    var body = ""
    res.write = function(data) {
      body = data.toString('UTF8')
      cookie = (/<cookie><!\[CDATA\[wenvjgol=(.+)\]\]><\/cookie>/g.exec(
        body) || ["", undefined])[1]
      if (cookie) console.log('found cookie: ' + cookie)
      res.oldWrite(data);
    }
    ...
    if (cookie) {
      res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'wenvjgol=' + cookie +
        '; Domain=otherwebsite.com; Path=/; Expires=' + new Date(Date.now() +
          1000 * 3600 * 24).toUTCString())
    }
    next();
  },
  function(req, res) {
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
      res.end();
      return;
    }
    proxy.web(req, res);
  }
).listen(8101);
```

Now when I reach `/login` I see
`cookie found: 1gmriba47wlc4ow4k88k8o8044gskso8sc4s0c8k40gcs44g8og40c8sks00so8og`

The cookie is not set on the first request for some reasons. So I make a first request somewhere on the other server (always via the proxy).

In the response headers there is

```
Set-Cookie: wenvjgol=1gmriba47wlc4ow4k88k8o8044gskso8sc4s0c8k40gcs44g8og40c8sks00so8og; Domain=anotherdomain.com; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 21 Oct 2014 11:23:55 GMT
```

And chrome detects it. But when I want to make the request to the url and it is necessary to be logged in, no cookie, not in the request nor in the response :(

This, is how I do it in angular:

```
$auth.login($event).then (sid) ->
  console.log 'sid is', sid

  $http(
    method: "GET"
    url: "#{config.domain}/forums"
    withCredentials: true
    # headers:
      # "Cookie": "wenvjgol=#{sid}"
  )
.then ->
  $http(
    method: "GET"
    url: "#{config.domain}/forums/5-#{$routeParams.id}-#{$routeParams.topic}-1-0-1-0-0.xml"
    withCredentials: true
    # headers:
      # "Cookie": "wenvjgol=#{sid}"
  )
.then console.log
```

The complete proxy file is here : https://gist.github.com/vinz243/fd01b77ef309101976a5

I hope I was clear.